# How to pass a Jinja2 to HiveQL using Python

Tags: python, hive, jinja2, airflow

I'm using Gcloud Composer as my Airflow. When I try to use Jinja in my HQL code, it does not translate it correctly.
I know that the [HiveOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/hive_operator.py) has a Jinja translator as I'm used to it, but the [DataProcHiveOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py) doesn't.

I've tried to use the HiveConf directly into my HQL files, but when setting those values to my Partition (i.e. `INSERT INTO TABLE abc PARTITION (ds = ${hiveconf:ds})`)`, it doesn't work. 
I have also added the following to my HQL file:

```
SET ds=to_date(current_timestamp());

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

But it didn't work as HIVE is transforming the formula above into a STRING.

So my idea was to combine both operators to have the Jinja translator working fine, but when I do that, I get the following error: `ERROR - submit() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`.

I'm not very familiar with Python coding and any help would be great, see below code for the operator I'm trying to build;

Header of the Python File (please note that the file contains other Operators not mentioned in this question):

```
import ntpath
import os
import re
import time
import uuid
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_dataproc_hook import DataProcHook
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.version import version
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from airflow.utils import timezone
from airflow.utils.operator_helpers import context_to_airflow_vars
```

modified DataprocHiveOperator:

```
class DataProcHiveOperator(BaseOperator):

template_fields = ['query', 'variables', 'job_name', 'cluster_name', 'dataproc_jars']
template_ext = ('.q',)
ui_color = '#0273d4'

@apply_defaults
def __init__(
        self,
        query=None,
        query_uri=None,
        hiveconfs=None,
        hiveconf_jinja_translate=False,
        variables=None,
        job_name='{{task.task_id}}_{{ds_nodash}}',
        cluster_name='cluster-1',
        dataproc_hive_properties=None,
        dataproc_hive_jars=None,
        gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
        delegate_to=None,
        region='global',
        job_error_states=['ERROR'],
        *args,
        **kwargs):

    super(DataProcHiveOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.gcp_conn_id = gcp_conn_id
    self.delegate_to = delegate_to
    self.query = query
    self.query_uri = query_uri
    self.hiveconfs = hiveconfs or {}
    self.hiveconf_jinja_translate = hiveconf_jinja_translate
    self.variables = variables
    self.job_name = job_name
    self.cluster_name = cluster_name
    self.dataproc_properties = dataproc_hive_properties
    self.dataproc_jars = dataproc_hive_jars
    self.region = region
    self.job_error_states = job_error_states

def prepare_template(self):
    if self.hiveconf_jinja_translate:
        self.query_uri= re.sub(
            "(\$\{(hiveconf:)?([ a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\})", "{{ \g<3> }}", self.query_uri)

def execute(self, context):
    hook = DataProcHook(gcp_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id,
                        delegate_to=self.delegate_to)

    job = hook.create_job_template(self.task_id, self.cluster_name, "hiveJob",
                                   self.dataproc_properties)

    if self.query is None:
        job.add_query_uri(self.query_uri)
    else:
        job.add_query(self.query)

    if self.hiveconf_jinja_translate:
        self.hiveconfs = context_to_airflow_vars(context)
    else:
        self.hiveconfs.update(context_to_airflow_vars(context))

    job.add_variables(self.variables)
    job.add_jar_file_uris(self.dataproc_jars)
    job.set_job_name(self.job_name)

    job_to_submit = job.build()
    self.dataproc_job_id = job_to_submit["job"]["reference"]["jobId"]

    hook.submit(hook.project_id, job_to_submit, self.region, self.job_error_states)
```

I would like to be able to use Jinja templating inside my HQL code to allow partition automation on my data pipeline.

P.S: I'll use the Jinja templating mostly for Partition DateStamp

Does anyone know what is the error message I'm getting + help me solve it?

`ERROR - submit() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the 5th argument `job_error_states` which is only in master and not in the current stable release (`1.10.1`).

Source Code for 1.10.1 -> https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/76a5fc4d2eb3c214ca25406f03b4a0c5d7250f71/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataproc_hook.py#L219

So remove that parameter and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Kaxil. It removed the error I was seeing. :D
Now I need to find a way to make the Translator work.